# Returning a struct containing a pointer to the first element of an array

Tags: c, struct

Running this code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char* f() {
    char s[] = "Hello, world!";
    return s;
}

int main() {
    printf("%s", f());
    return 0;
}
```

prints `(null)`. This makes sense to me: The `char` array is valid only in the scope of `f`, so the pointer returned is not valid. However, if I create a struct containing the pointer to the array

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct word {
    char* str;
} word;

word f() {
    char str[] = "Hello, world!";
    return (word) { str };
}

int main() {
    printf("%s", f().str);
    return 0;
}
```

this will now "work", i. e. it will print `Hello, world!`.

Now I am wondering why it does; shouldn't the pointer here be invalid too, because the array it points to was created in `f` and is thus not valid anymore? Or is this just undefined behavior and I got "lucky" that nothing else was pushed onto the stack at that location? Or is there a mistake in my reasoning (I am rather new to C).

I haven't been able to find information on this specific behavior, only for structs containing arrays of constant size. I have tested this using `gcc` version `9.4.0` (which uses `gnu11` "standard" as default). I would appreciate if anyone could point me to the explanation of this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or is this just undefined behavior and I got "lucky" that nothing else was pushed onto the stack at that location?

That is correct. The line

```
printf("%s", f().str);
```

will invoke undefined behavior by dereferencing a [dangling pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer). This means that anything may happen; your program may crash or it may appear to work as intended.

The compiler clang is actually able to detect this error at run-time, if you compile with `-fsanitize=address`. [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/PPna7MG8M) is an online demonstration.

For further explanation, you may want to read [this answer to a similar C++ question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6445794/12149471), which contains an interesting analogy. Most of the information in the answer also applies to C.